# how to add checkbox to cells in react bootstrap table2 header cells?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table-next and wanted to add "checboxes" to some of the header cells. I referred to the documentation- [https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Welcome&selectedStory=react%20bootstrap%20table%202%20&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyh3b.png)  but could not find a relevant example. Can any one please help?

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

class Container extends React.Component{

    render(){
        <BootstrapTable keyField="PartNumber" selectRow={selectRowProp}
                    data={this.state.data} columns={this.state.columns}/>
    }

}
```

Expected output of checboxes in header cells -

[image]

Comment: Is the left icon in 'Part Number' meant to be a checkbox?

Comment: Yes.. All those icons in the cells are checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "headerFormatter" to customize header cells. Below are the working code and output screenshot

```
state = {
    columns: MYResult.ParametricList_Attributes || []
};

componentDidMount(){
    const checkbox = (column, colIndex) => {
        //console.log(colIndex)
        //console.log("column text "+column.text)
        if("Part Number"==column.text || "Product Line"==column.text){
            return (
                <div>
                    {column.text}  
                    <span><input type="checkbox" name="something" value="" /></span>
                </div>
            );
        }else{
            return (
            <div>
                {column.text}  
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
    const newColumn = this.state.columns.map((column) => {
        //console.log("column --"+column.text)
            return {...column, headerFormatter: checkbox};
    });
    //console.log("newColumn --"+newColumn)
    this.setState({columns: newColumn });
}
```

[image]